# Oracle 12c column_name inconsistency

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

So I have this small problem with Oracle 12c.
Whenever I do a query like

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'EMP';
```

I get the column names in the right order

```
empno
ename
...
```

but when I run it again the column names get reversed.

```
deptno
comm
...
ename
empno
```

Anyone knows why this happens? Is this a new "feature" implemented in 12c or it's just me that get this the wrong way? And most important is there a way to fix this?
Thanks in advance and sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: What's right order? Add ORDER BY to always get the same order. (Otherwise you can't expect any specific order.)

Comment: of course you should use `ORDER BY` to get deterministic output. Does it really change every time? Oracle usually does not change execution plans so often. The change in exec plans can be caused by: statistic re-calculations, some dynamic sampling curiosity or by performance baselines. If execution plan really changed with every execution, then maybe you found a bug in Oracle.

Comment: Thing is whenever I run this query on a 11g database the result stays the same(first thing I posted, the order of columns being the one specified when the table was first created). But when I do the same query on a 12c database the first result is the first thing posted, the following being the second result. I don't know why this happens. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: Theoretically this could be cause by the feature called "Performance baselines". Oracle remembers exec. plans for queries and also some real-life performance data for each plan. Optimizer might generate some "suboptimal" plan for the 1st execution. Then after execution it notices that the plan did not perform so good, so it  reverts back to previous plan from "Performance baseline repository". It's hard to validate if you do see exec. plans for each execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
order by column_id;
```

and you will allways get the right order of columns